# Show that element which is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three `div` element. When you click on them, they will be hide. Also there is a button which it should shows that hidden element.

Here is my codes:

```js
$("div").click(function(e) {
  $(this).hide();
});

$("body").on('click', '.close_cmnt_edit', function(e) { 
   /* how to show that element which is hide? */
});
```

```css
div{
border:1px solid gray;
padding 15px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">anything1</div>
<div class="test2">anything2</div>
<div class="test3">anything3</div>

<br><br>
<button>show that element which is hide </button>
```

**Note:** If there is more than one-hidden-element, It have to show them according to hide-order. For e.g: In first `div.test2` has been hided and then `div.test1` has been hided. So, when I click on that button, in first `div.test2` have to be show and then `div.test1`.

Comment: If you need ordering like that, you need something to keep track of the elements, for instance an array holding the elements, that you can pop them off as they are shown again.

Comment: @adeneo What do you mean of `array` exactly? A JavaScript array of something like localStorage?

Comment: Unless you need to keep track across pageloads, a regular array should be fine

Comment: It's really not hard -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v2r4z407/4/**

Comment: @adeneo Very thanks ..! However the order of showing in your fiddle is exactly inverse than what I mentioned in my question.. But ok, I got the theory ...! Also you can write an answer under my question.

Comment: "inverse order"? Then you probably want to shift instead of popping, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v2r4z407/5/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one element hidden, or to show all the hidden elements, you can do this:

```
$("body").on('click', '.close_cmnt_edit', function(e) { 
   $("div:hidden").show();
});
```

For showing the ordering of the elements, you can use an array data as a stack.

```js
// Create a track of all the elements.
hiddenElements = [];

$("div").click(function(e) {
  hiddenElements = hiddenElements.reverse();
  hiddenElements.push($(this).attr("class"));
  hiddenElements = hiddenElements.reverse();
  $(this).hide();
});

$("body").on('click', 'button', function(e) { 
   $("." + hiddenElements.pop()).show();
});
```

```css
div{
border:1px solid gray;
padding 15px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">anything1</div>
<div class="test2">anything2</div>
<div class="test3">anything3</div>

<br><br>
<button>show that element which is hide </button>
```

Reverse the array using `hiddenElements = hiddenElements.reverse();`.

Comment: Good. but please add that array to your solution ..! *(because actually that is my main question)*

Comment: @Shafizadeh I just added. `:)`

Comment: Too fast `:-)`, But I don't know why when I click on that button, nothing happens ..

Comment: @Shafizadeh Debugging it. Please wait.

Comment: @Shafizadeh YOu forgot to add the class to the button.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Click on 2 and then 3. First 3 will be shown and then 2 will then be shown. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: nope, exactly inverse ...! Click on 2 and then 3, Now I want first 2 and then 3.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Check. Updated. `:D`

Comment: @Shafizadeh Reverse the array using `hiddenElements = hiddenElements.reverse();`.

Comment: `:D` Yeah I will ...!

Comment: @Shafizadeh Yay! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo mentioned in the comments, this would be fine:

**Regular order:**

```js
var arr = [];

$("div").click(function(e) {
  arr.push($(this).hide());
});

$(document).on('click', '.close_cmnt_edit', function(e) { 
   arr.pop().show();
});
```

```css
div{
border:1px solid gray;
padding 15px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">anything1</div>
<div class="test2">anything2</div>
<div class="test3">anything3</div>
<br><br>
<button class="close_cmnt_edit">show that element which is hide </button>
```

**Inverse order**: *(what I wanted in the question)*

```js
var arr = [];

$("div").click(function(e) {
  arr.push($(this).hide());
});

$(document).on('click', '.close_cmnt_edit', function(e) { 
   arr.shift().show();
});
```

```css
div{
border:1px solid gray;
padding 15px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">anything1</div>
<div class="test2">anything2</div>
<div class="test3">anything3</div>
<br><br>
<button class="close_cmnt_edit">show that element which is hide </button>
```